# Jest: Test suite failed to run | Cannot find module 'core/tracking/gtm'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, jestjs, react-testing-library

I get the following error every time i try to run test:
[ivan-kramarenko@fedora shortage-global-frontend]$ sudo npm run test

> test
> jest

PASS  **tests**/productSlug.test.tsx
● Test suite failed to run

```
Cannot find module 'core/tracking/gtm' from 'src/pages/[organizationSlug]/products/[productSlug]/index.tsx'

Require stack:
  src/pages/[organizationSlug]/products/[productSlug]/index.tsx
  __tests__/productSlug.test.tsx

  21 | import {
  22 |   Breadcrumbs,
> 23 |   getHomeCrumb,
     |                          ^
  24 |   getOrganizationCrumb,
  25 |   getProductCrumb,
  26 | } from 'components/breadcrumbs/breadcrumbs';

  at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:324:11)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/pages/[organizationSlug]/products/[productSlug]/index.tsx:23:52)
```

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.461 s
Ran all test suites.

I was try to move **tests** folder from src/pages/.. to root directory, but it not helped.

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example